# I2C camera not working 100% of the time

Tags: power-supply, fpga, pcb-design, soldering, camera

This is my stereoscopic system:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm using a zedboard to pilot two i2c-camera MT9D111:
http://www.dragonwake.com/download/camera/MT9D111/mt9d111_rev5.pdf

Camera PCB Information:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2_rhDNAxM4sMWM2MmQ5MWMtNTFjMS00Y2YzLTgzNGUtYjEwMWZlMDg1NjM2/view

I'm encountering problem using i2c-cadence driver on an ArchLinux Distro.

The two i2c cameras are always detected by i2cdetect tool, but if i try to write to them sometimes they work correctly, but other times i get:

```
Something went wrong with write()! Error: 11 - Resource temporarily unavailable (addr:93)
```

or worst:

```
Something went wrong with write()! Error: 6 - No such device or address (addr:93)
```

I do not know why this error are popping out totally randomly, can someone explain this weird behaviour? Are the wire to long for I2C protocol (400KHz)? Is something related to the power supply?

I'm going crazy about this issue, any help will be useful.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm preeeettty sure that the black foam your board is on is conductive, which is bad if your Zedboard is on

Comment: i always tought it was isolant .-.

Comment: There are some that aren't, tahts I why put the disclaimer at the front of the last one.  Its generally not advised to run the electronics on top of the packaging you receive them in though.  It is advised to run them on top of something you know for sure won't harm the devices

Comment: It's always possible one of the two I2C devices is holding the line. I am not to familiar with doing this through Linux though, so not sure if that would give you that error.

Comment: the two cameras use different busses and the problem persist with only one camera

Comment: @Funkyguy no difference with or without the foam :(

Comment: @Luca Do you have an oscilloscope or logic analyzer to poke the bus to actually see what's going in it?

Comment: @ricardomenzer yep, i can actually see the signal coming from the zedboard, but sometime the camera does not reply

Comment: @Luca Are these signals well shaped? Voltage levels, timings? Can you post a picture of them when it doesn't work?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I use the camera with an STM32F7discovery board and sometimes it does not respond anymore. In these cases, the only solution is power cycling the whole board.

Comment: What data speeds are present on those long, mismatched-length, unshielded wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that Vivado assure a PULL UP on the selected pins it is a **WEAK PULL UP**, adding an external PULL UP resistor has solved the problem.

Comment: Reading the question in combination with this answer it doesn't seem like it would be all that helpful to anyone else. Perhaps you could share the init code that worked?

Comment: i'm working on it

Comment: @PeterJ After other experiments the final solution was to add external pull up resistor.